# Can't set use Unicode Utf-8 in windows server 2016?

Tags: utf-8

I have a problem.

A ubuntu server and a windows server sending file's each other by NFS.

But, When windows copy the file from ubuntu, That file's name and content's characters are brokend.

So, I want to try Windows server's locale setting.

In my windows10 Can setting use UTF-8 locale. like this.

[image]

But disappear that check box which use Unicode UTF-8 at Windows server 2016's locale setting's screen.

Have some idea? Thank you.

Comment: It's an experimental(Beta) setting in Window 10 only.

Comment: Mark Tolonen // Thank you.